# Overriding a variadic method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, subclassing, variadic-functions

When subclassing in objective-c, how can I forward a call to the superclass in the case of a variadic method. By what should I replace the ??? below to send all the objects I got?

```
- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
   [super appendObjects: ???];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. To safely pass all the variadic arguments, you need a method to accept a `va_list`.

In super,

```
-(void)appendObjectsWithArguments:(va_list)vl {
  ...
}

-(void)appendObject:(id)firstObject, ...
  va_list vl;
  va_start(vl, firstObject);
  [self appendObjectsWithArguments:vl];
  va_end(vl);
}
```

And use `[super appendObjectsWithArguments:vl]` when you override the method in the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
   va_list args = &firstObject;
   [super appendObjects: args];
}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, read the manual pages on varargs.

Comment: That won't work, it will just pass "args" as a single parameter to appendObjects (and probably cause a fault into the bargain).