# Objective-C - Missing sentinel in method dispatch?

Tags: objective-c, warnings, uialertview

I am trying to override the init method for a UIAlertView and customize it and I am getting the following warning? "Missing sentinel in method dispatch".

What does this warning mean, and how can I resolve it?

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
            message:(NSString *)message 
           delegate:(id)delegate 
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    if (self = [super initWithTitle:title 
                            message:message 
                           delegate:delegate 
                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle 
                  otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles]) 
    {
        // Customize alertView
    }

    return  self;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to add a UITextField in my Alert, and I don't want to use the new API in iOS 5 because I want my app to run on 4.0 devices and higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`UIAlertView` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), in particular:

> ## Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view  hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

This means overriding the `initWithTitle` method isn't going to be useful. You'll need to try another approach - perhaps if you share what you're trying to achieve people might be able to suggest an alternative (for example, using a category).

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be, that `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` variadic, i.e., takes an arbitrary number of arguments after the last parameter. When you call the base class' method, you have two problems:

- you are not passing all arguments along, that the caller of your version supplied, and
- you are not passing the final `nil` after the last argument (which I presume is, what the compiler is complaining about).

As others have already noted, `UIAlertView` is not intended to be subclassed. Consider trying another approach (using convenience constructor functions/methods instead).

Answer (score 1):

It's warning because you're not putting a `nil` (the sentinel) at the end of the variadic method call. But, you're out of luck with overriding a variadic method anyway. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987209/overriding-a-variadic-method-in-objective-c) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't subclass `UIAlertView`.  From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
>   and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
>   private and must not be modified.